# How to sync state in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am having difficulty updating my state and my component. After a button is pressed and I change the value of one of the props of the popup component. The value of the props is not updated. I believe that this is one of the side effects of using the setstate. I did some research and saw that there is a way to solve this problem using the useeffect hook but I am unable to receive the result. Here is my code below:

My goal is to get from the form having the prop of Data0 to have a prop of Data1, but the prop does not seem to be updating at all.
I am simulating clicking multiple objects and the result is an update in the value of fromData. Thus, app.js is my parent component. The child component is the popup, whose value should change to Bob and an actual date instead of just string values of the original name and original date.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormDialog from './component/popup'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


function App() {
  const Data0 = { name:'original name', date:'original date' }
  const Data1 = { name:'Bob', date:'1939' }
  const [formStatus, setformStatus] = React.useState(false);
  const [formdata2, setformData2] = useState(Data0)
  const [tempform, settempform] = useState(<FormDialog formStatus = {formStatus} handelForm={() => handelForm()} Data0={Data0}/>)


  const handelForm = () => {
    const tempform = <FormDialog formStatus = {formStatus} handelForm={() => handelForm()} Data0={Data1}/>
    settempform(tempform);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tempform = <FormDialog formStatus = {formStatus} handelForm={() => handelForm()} Data0={Data1}/>
    settempform(tempform);
    setformStatus(!formStatus);
    console.log('formdata2 EFFECT', formdata2)
    settempform(tempform);
    setformStatus(!formStatus);
    setformStatus(!formStatus);
  }, [formdata2]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <h4 align='center'>Render Custom Component in Material Table</h4>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => handelForm()}>
        Vendor row
      </Button>
      {tempform}
      {formdata2.billingVendor}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

````
export default function FormDialog (props) {
  let [Data, setData] = React.useState(props.Data0);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog
        maxWidth='lg'
        open={props.formStatus}
        aria-labelledby="max-width-dialog-title"
        disableBackdropClick= {true}
        disableEscapeKeyDown={true}
      >
        <DialogTitle className={classes.title}>{Data.name}</DialogTitle>
        <Divider />
        <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
                Please be cautious when updating the fields below.
            </DialogContentText>
            <form noValidate>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth= {true}>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label='Date'
                        style={{ margin: 8 }}
                        disabled
                        value={Data.name}
                        variant="outlined"
                        />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label='Date'
                        style={{ margin: 8 }}
                        disabled
                        value={Data.name}
                        variant="outlined"
                        />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        style={{ margin: 8 }}
                        disabled
                        value={Data.date}
                        variant="outlined"
                        />
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        style={{ margin: 8 }}
                        disabled
                        value={Data.date}
                        variant="outlined"
                        />
                    <br/>
                    
                    </div>

                </FormControl>
            </form>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={() => props.handelForm()} color="primary">
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}```
````

Comment: You are creating a new state based on the value of the props in your child component, which is **independent** to the state in the parent component. So a change in the child cannot be passed back to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the process you are following is not a good one. You shouldn't store a react component in the state rather you should dynamically load the component or pass what prop you need.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormDialog from './component/popup'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


function App() {
  const Data0 = { name:'original name', date:'original date' }
  const Data1 = { name:'Bob', date:'1939' }
  const [formStatus, setformStatus] = React.useState(false);
  const [formdata2, setformData2] = useState(Data0)
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(Data0)


  const handelForm = () => {
    // here change the state however you want

    setFormData(Data0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <h4 align='center'>Render Custom Component in Material Table</h4>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => handelForm()}>
        Vendor row
      </Button>
       <FormDialog formStatus = {formStatus} handelForm={() => handelForm()} Data0={formData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the `FormDialog` add the useEffect to perform the change

```
useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.Data0)
}, [props.Data0])
```

This is update the state with the changes

Comment: This does not result in the props that are passed into the FormDialog to be updated. Please try running the code above. Thanks!

Comment: Because I didn't pass the updated props. You have to update the value as you like inside ```handelForm```

Comment: I added the lines setFormData(Data1);
    setformStatus(true);

Comment: In the popup, the values that are shown are still the original values

Comment: I have updated the solution. We have to look for changes in the ```FormDialog``` and update the state using ```useEffect```

Comment: Thank works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new state based on the value of the props in your child component, which is **independent** to the state in the parent component. So a change in the child cannot be passed back to the parent.

To fix it,

1. create the state in your parent component by

```
const [Data0, setData0] = useState({ name:'original name', date:'original date' })
```

2. pass the `setState` function to change the value in the parent component to your children by

```
const tempform = <FormDialog formStatus = {formStatus} handelForm={() => handelForm()} Data={Data1} setData={setData0}/>
```

3. change the value in your child component accordingly

```
let {Data, setData} = props;
```

Then the call of `setData` should be calling the one in your parent component and it should be able to update the value accordingly.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. I should be more clear that I am simulating clicking multiple objects and the result is an update in the value of fromData. Thus, app.js is my parent component. The child component is the popup, whose value should change to Bob and a actual date instead of just string values of original name and original date.